# What does the word "deroutinization" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> The ultimate source of the massive spontaneous militancy and
> disruption that threatened public order lay in the radical increase in
> unemployment and the collapse of wage rates for those lucky enough
> still to be employed. The normal conditions that sustained routine
> politics suddenly evaporated. Neither the routines of governance nor
> the routines of institutionalized opposition and representation made
> much sense. At the individual level, the **deroutinization** took the form
> of vagrancy, crime, and vandalism. Collectively, it took the form of
> spontaneous defiance in riots, factory occupations, violent strikes,
> and tumultuous demonstrations. What made the rush of reforms possible
> were the social forces unleashed by the Depression, which seemed
> beyond the ability of political elites, property owners, *and, it
> should be noted*, trade unions and left-wing parties to master. The
> hand of the elites was forced. — James C. Scott

Am I correct to assume that the word means something along the line of "an engagement in extra-institutional politics"?

Comment: **Deroutinization** means the process of de-routine-izing (something); that is, that the process of making normal poilitical conditions non-routine "took the form of vagrancy..."

Comment: And *routinize* does at least have a [dictionary entry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/routinize)